# Primitive element theorem for function fields of curves

Tags: number-theory

If $k$ is a perfect field, and $L/K$ is a finite extension of two function fields over $k,$ by which I mean $L, K$ both have transcendence degree 1 over $k$, is $L/K$ always simple? It seems like every example of a non-simple extension I can find online is about more than one dimension.